# Rails counting rows with has_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, count, has-many

I have:

```
class Constituency < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :votes
end

class Vote <ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :constituency
end
```

Now, what I want to do is to create a table, that will show me Name of constituency, number of voters (which is easy, as it is part of the table Constituency) and number of votes that were given in this constituency.
The beginning looks like this:

```
<% @constituencies.each do |constituency| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= constituency.name %></td>
    <td><%= constituency.voters %></td>
```

So now comes my question: how can I count all rows in Votes, but with division based on constituency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`constituency.votes.count` should give you the correct count for each different constituency. Hope this helps.

```
<% @constituencies.each do |constituency| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= constituency.name %></td>
    <td><%= constituency.voters %></td>
    <td><%= constituency.votes.count %></td>
```

Comment: Oh, thank you! It was so easy and I was trying with double loops and other unnecessary things! I don't know, why I didn't think about it. Thanks again.

Comment: If someone answers your question you should accept it by clicking on the link which is below the up and down vote links. Courtesy.